# Query MongoDB for nested Arrays

Tags: mongodb

Need help for formatting query to find/get values using search parameters with nested Array.

**I have an collection as follows**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b3ad55f66479332a0482961",
        "timestamp": "2018-06-17T00:30:00.000Z",
        "deviceid": "123456",
        "values": [
            {
                "minval": 1,
                "minvalues": [
                    {
                        "secval": 51,
                        "secvalues": {                            
                            "alt": "300",
                            "mcc": "404",
                            "mnc": "46",
                            "priority": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "secval": 52,
                        "secvalues": {                            
                            "alt": "300",
                            "mcc": "404",
                            "mnc": "46",
                            "priority": 1
                        }
                    },                                        
                    {
                        "secval": 56,
                        "secvalues": {
                            "alt": "300",
                            "mcc": "404",
                            "mnc": "46",
                            "priority": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**need the out as follows with search properties as "values.minvalues.secvalues.priority"**

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b3ad55f66479332a0482961",
        "timestamp": "2018-06-17T00:30:00.000Z",
        "deviceid": "123456",
        "values": [
            {
                "minval": 1,
                "minvalues": [                    
                    {
                        "secval": 56,
                        "secvalues": {
                            "alt": "300",
                            "mcc": "404",
                            "mnc": "46",
                            "priority": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**I tried the following query but with out success**

```
dbRetval.db('ls_gpsdatabase').collection('gpsevent').aggregate([
            { "$match": { "deviceid": { "$in": idList}}},
            { "$sort": { "_id": -1} },
            {"$unwind":"$values.minvalues.secvalues"},
            //{"$project":{"deviceid":1,"values.minvalues.secvalues.lat":1,"values.minvalues.secvalues.min":1}} ,
            { "$match": { "values.minvalues.secvalues.priority": { "$eq": 1}}},
            { "$group": { "_id": "$deviceid" , "doc": { "$push": "$values.minvalues.secvalues" }}} ]).toArray();
```

If any can help that would be great full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) to replace existing field. Since you have two levels of nested arrays you can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) for outer and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) for inner to check your condition:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { 
           "_id": "5b3ad55f66479332a0482961",
           "timestamp": "2018-06-17T00:30:00.000Z"
        } 
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            values: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$values",
                    as: "value",
                    in: {
                        minval: "$$value.minval",
                        minvalues: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$$value.minvalues",
                                as: "minvalue",
                                cond: {
                                    $eq: [ "$$minvalue.secvalues.priority", 0 ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the Query,also could you let me know how do we filter based on the timestamp and ID along with the above your query plz.

Comment: @TrackGPs edited my answer, you need additional `$match` stage